# How to using positioned z-index in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My UI seems to be hidden, how can I make it pop, I'm using Widget `Positioned`

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/708Xi.jpg)

Example:

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jHHW.png)

I'm newbie, Many thanks all !

Comment: Put your implemented widget code too, then we can help you better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your stack, set the clipBehavior property to Clip.none.

```dart
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  ...
);
```